# Angular table filter with checkbox not working

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I am making a project with Angular. First, I added a checkbox feature to my table. I can select any or all of the rows I want and process them. Then I added the filtering feature to my table. When I search by word, I show the appropriate ones in my table. The problem starts when I want to use both at the same time. I am filtering, when I select all the incoming filtered data, it selects the entire table, the filter feature does not work in the checkbox section, can you help me?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-with-selection-checkbox?file=app%2Ftable-selection-example.ts

/*html*/

```
                    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" style="font-size: 12px;">
                        <mat-label>Search</mat-label>
                        <mat-icon matPrefix>search</mat-icon>
                        <input type="search" matInput  [(ngModel)]="search">
                    </mat-form-field>

             
             
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered"
                            filterControl="true">
                            <thead class=" text-primary">
                                <th>
                                    <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? toggleAllRows() : null"
                                        [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                                        [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()">
                                    </mat-checkbox>
                                </th>
                                <th> NO.</th>
                                <th >NAME.</th>
                                <th >SURNAME</th>
                                <th >E-MAIL</th>
                                <th >SCHOOL NAME</th>
                                
                            </thead>

                            <tbody>
                                <tr
                                    *ngFor="let person of dataPersonList | filter: search ;  let i =index ">
                                    <td>
                                        <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                                            (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(person) : null"
                                            [checked]="selection.isSelected(person)">
                                        </mat-checkbox>
                                    </td>
                                    <td> {{i+1}}</td>
                                    <td> {{person.name}} </td>
                                    <td> {{person.surname}}</td>
                                    <td> {{person.email}}</td>
                                    <td> {{person.schoolName}}</td>
                                    

                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                     </div>
```

/*component*/

```
/*TABLE FILTER */
  search:string;



  /** Whether the number of selected elements matches the total number of rows. */
  isAllSelected() {
    const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
    const numRows = this.dataPersonList.length;
    return numSelected === numRows;


  }

  /** Selects all rows if they are not all selected; otherwise clear selection. */
  toggleAllRows() {
    if (this.isAllSelected()) {
      this.selection.clear();
      return;
    }
    this.selection.select(...this.dataPersonList);
  }
```

/*pipe*/

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(values: any, filter: string): any {

    if (!filter || filter.length === 0) {
      return values;
    }

    if (values.length === 0) {
      return values;
    }

    return values.filter((value: any) => {

      let name;
        name = value.name.toLocaleUpperCase().indexOf(filter.toLocaleUpperCase()) !== -1;
     

      let surname;
        surname = value.surname.toLocaleUpperCase().indexOf(filter.toLocaleUpperCase()) !== -1;
     

      let email;
        email = value.email.toLocaleUpperCase().indexOf(filter.toLocaleUpperCase()) !== -1;
    

      let schoolName;
        schoolName = value.schoolName.toLocaleUpperCase('tr-TR').indexOf(filter.toLocaleUpperCase('tr-TR')) !== -1;
     

      if (name || surname || email || schoolName ) {
        return value;
      }
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `filteredData` instead `data` (see the [API](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatTableDataSource))

```
  isAllSelected() {
    const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
    //here is filteredData
    const numRows = this.dataSource.filteredData.length;
    //here is >= not ===
    return numSelected >= numRows;
  }

  masterToggle() {
    // if there is a selection then clear that selection
    if (this.isSomeSelected()) {
      this.selection.clear();
    } else {
      //here also is filteredData
      this.isAllSelected()
        ? this.selection.clear()
        : this.dataSource.filteredData.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
    }
  }
```

Your [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-with-selection-checkbox-diemtp?file=app%2Ftable-selection-example.ts,app%2Ftable-selection-example.html) with a simple filter (button click make a filter/remove filter)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It will be another responsibility.


My data: dataSource : PeriodicElement[]=[]; in this way.

In the code in the example: dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement>(ELEMENT_DATA);


I get errors elsewhere in the code when defining MatTableDataSource. (sorting options)


https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fexample%2Fsort-overview-example.ts 


Therefore I cannot use the filtered feature. Are there any other indicators of help?

Comment: @zdnmn, you can use as "dataSource" of a mat-table an array **or** a MatTableDataSource. Only in the case you use a MatTableDataSourceyou can use the filter, sort, pagination... (this is the `this.dataSource=MatTableDataSource<..>(your array)`. If you use a simple array you can not take advantage of this characteristics (you need implement yourself)